# div's height:100% on 27 inch monitor is not working

Tags: html, css, markup, screen-resolution

I have used this technique to made my div's height be 100%:

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
}

#myDiv {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and everything is perfect on usual devices, however on screens with large resolutions(27 inch) it is not working properly, how can i fix that?
thanks!

Comment: `100%` is `100%` regardless of the size of the monitor. Perhaps you want to use [viewport-relative lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1317805) instead?

Comment: should we assume #myDiv is a child of BODY ?

Comment: What is not working properly? Check with inspect element what is going on :)

Comment: yes, it is a part of the body

Comment: i tried hv and it's the same

Comment: please could you share a fiddle with the actual style and markup? can you reproduce the issue on a minimal example? Otherwise we could just guessing.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski it is not 100% of the window height

Comment: In what way is it not 100%? does it stop short, start late...more detail is needed.

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle. That would make the debugging so much easier

Answer (score 0):

set default margin of body tag to 0px, may be it will work.
e.g. 
I have added below code it work fine for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type='text/css'>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin:0px;
        }
        #myDiv {
            height: 100%;
            background:red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='myDiv'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

Your div needs to be positioned absolutely.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;  
}
html, body, .parent {
 height: 100%;
}
.parent {
 background: red; /* for visual */
 position: relative; /* needed */
}
.child {
 background:blue; /* for visual */
 position: absolute; /* needed */
 top: 50%; /* needed */
 transform: translateY(-50%); /* needed */
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='child'>Hello.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that's not required at all, and would in any case be more harmful (for general cases)...

Comment: I'm not recommending it, because it will obviously cause other issues with the design, such as having to use 97% height instead of 100% or use hide overflow to avoid the scroll where none should be present, and in most cases where a scroll must be present the background will become unaligned, not to mention that when the browser is resized. But he asked why his "html,.body{}" cheat didn't work, and I replied, promptly, with the correct answer. Personally, I would recommend using javascript to measure the height of the dom and div he wants aligned, but he didn't ask for that.

Comment: To remove scrollbars you need to reset the default body margins so the height is 100% :)

Comment: to be prompt and not be correct is way more harmful than helpful.